# iterating pointer gives array subscript is above array bounds error

Tags: c

I have seen allot of posts about the **array subscript is above array bounds error** and i understand it happends when the iterator equals the max size of the array but my case is different:

```
static inline void setUninitialized(uint32 * xoBuff, uint32 xiItemSize)
{
    uint32 i;
    for (i=0 ; i < (xiItemSize/sizeof(uint32)) ; i++)
    {
        *(xoBuff++) = (uint32)MAP_UNINITIALIZED_VALUE;
    }
}
```

when i run this code i get the **array subscript is above array bounds error** but i cant figure out why, i have literally tried all the posible combinations of incrementing the iterator and casting all kinds of variables.
the definition of uint32 is:

```
typedef unsigned long  uint32;
```

any ideas why this keeps happening?

EDIT:
the way that the function is called is as follows:

```
TableEntry sEntry;

setUninitialized((uint32 *)&sEntry.policyKey, sizeof(PolicyKey));
```

the policyKey field is of instance PolicyKey

Comment: How is the function called (and how are the arguments declared in the caller)?

Comment: Why `xiItemSize/sizeof(uint32)`? Shouldn't it be `xiTemSize` by itself?

Comment: What do you mean `array subscript is above array bounds error`?  How are you determining that?

Comment: @FiddlingBits If `xiTemSize` is a result of calling `sizeof` on something, then the division by `sizeof(uint32)` is correct.

Comment: Are you using valgrind or some other memory profiler to get this error?

Comment: @md5 i will add the calling block with edit

Comment: `xoBuff++` increments `xoBuff` one `uint32`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes that is why its /sizeof(uint32)

Comment: `setUninitialized((uint32 *)&sEntry.policyKey, sizeof(sEntry.policyKey));` would be better.

Comment: What is `PolicyKey` exactly (I mean: is it a typedef from array type for example)?

Comment: @md5 its a struct that contains some uint32 fields and some other structs contains packed u8 and u16 fields

Comment: Do you get the same error if you declare `PolicyKey pk` and then call `setUninitialized((uint32*)&pk, sizeof(pk))`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes i do

Comment: Can you post a working example that we can run?

Comment: @FiddlingBits unfortunattly not

Comment: @Anton.P: You can try to reproduce the error with a smaller code. It'd easier to debug.

Comment: Please study how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names (and links) for the same basic idea. You should  reduce it to about 20 lines of code, possibly less. Unless you can do so, your question will be closed. Note that the name `uint32` is perilously close to `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>`/`<inttypes.h>`, and your definition of `uint32` is OK for a 32-bit Unix machine or a Windows machine but is wrong on a 64-bit Unix machine.

Comment: For instance, you probably only need `typedef struct TableEntry { PolicyKey policyKey; } TableEntry;` for one structure type.  The interesting part is probably the definition of the `…` in `typedef struct PolicyKey { … } PolicyKey;`.  You then need a function to hold the variable declaration and function call, and the code shoqn in the question.  That's about all.

Comment: [Are you using valgrind or some other memory profiler to get this error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186745/iterating-pointer-gives-array-subscript-is-above-array-bounds-error#comment39219777_25186745) (sorry - this is important so I ask again)

Comment: So my guess, `policyKey` isn't a `PolicyKey`;  its a `PolicyKey*`. Actually **posting real code** would clear  up the now 14-comments and growing list all asking the same thing, And the premise behind this is wrong anyway. If `PolicyKey` isn't a multiple of `sizeof(uint32)` on your platform, it won't be fully filled (the tail will remain unset), and I honestly cannot think of a sane reason anyone would do this. And `array subscript is above array bounds error` makes no sense either, as there are no arrays in this *anywhere*; only pointers and dereferences. Anyway vtc as nei.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
sizeof(PolicyKey)
```

doesn't give you the size of the array. You can't ever get the size of an array in C. Rather, it's giving you the size of the pointer `PolicyKey` (assuming that's what it is), which will always be the same size (probably 8). So then `(xiItemSize/sizeof(uint32))` will always (again assuming that everything on your computer is normally-sized) evaluate to 2.

It's hard to say anything else without knowing what `sEntry` looks like, but my guess is that you pass in a buffer that's only one-item long at some point, and it segfaults when it tries to dereference `*(xoBuff++)`.

Comment: hi, PolicyKey is a struct so there is no problem with that.
your guess was quite close the problem caused by the struct beeing packet. i changed the settings to memset and it fixed it.

Comment: @Anton.P Glad to hear you fixed your issue. Please upvote and/or accept this answer if it helped you out.